# Vue.js Navigation Sub Menus via WP REST API

Tags: vue.js, wordpress-rest-api

In inspiration from Sarah Drasner's Smashing Magazine article [Replacing jQuery with Vue](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/jquery-vue-javascript/), I've replaced all of my jQuery with Vue in my Wordpress theme. Things are going nicely as I've already replaced functionality for modals, form validation/submission, at the like. I even got a boost in my page speed grade from Google's page speed insights tool.

The last piece of my puzzle is finishing off my navigation menu. The menu is built and working, but I'm not happy with it. My primary dissatisfaction is in conditionally rendering submenus better. For example, menu items without children receive an empty child:

```
<ul class="submenu"></ul>
```

Here's what I have so far:

Here's the shape of my Nav menu data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/jfld4

Important property definitions:

- "obeject_id" is a unique indentifier
- "post_parent" refers to the nav item's parent "object_id"
- Notice notice top level menu items have "post_parent: 0"

Here's my Vue code for rendering the menu:" https://codepen.io/JosephAllen/pen/zLQqRr?editors=0011

```
<ul class="menu" id="primary-menu">
    <menu-item 
        v-for="item in navItems"
        v-if="item.post_parent == 0"
        :key="item.object_id"
        :class="{active: item.active}"
        v-bind:url="item.url"
        v-bind:object_id="item.object_id"
        v-bind:post_parent="item.post_parent"
        v-bind:title="item.title">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <menu-item 
                v-for="subItem in navItems"
                :key="subItem.object_id"
                v-if="subItem.post_parent == item.object_id"
                v-bind:object_id="subItem.object_id"
                v-bind:url="subItem.url"
                v-bind:ID="subItem.ID"
                v-bind:post_parent="subItem.post_parent"
                v-bind:title="subItem.title">
            </menu-item>
        </ul>
    </menu-item>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `<ul class="sub-menu">` element, include `v-if` or `v-show` with a test if the item contains any subItems (e.g. `<ul class="sub-menu" v-show="hasSubItems">` once you've computed `hasSubItems` of course). Check out [conditional rendering in the Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

Comment: The problem here is that the current shape of my data tels me if a nav item has a parent via "post_parent", but there is no property that tells me if a nav item has children.

I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: Rather than setting the result of your fetch from Wordpress to `this.navItems`, how about including another step to transform the data into a structure that will support your end goal a little easier and then set that to `this.navItems`. e.g. you could do a single iteration over the items returned from Wordpress, create a list, map or whatever data structure of your menu then use that.